# HumanIK Z axis Up in Maya for Unreal Engine

Tags: maya, unreal-4

I am pretty stumped! I want to use HumanIK in Maya to throw together some prototype animations for my game that is being developed in Unreal Engine 4.7

The issue is that Unreal requires Z axis to be UP and this results in HumanIK Skellies to end up on their backs in Maya when Created.

Is there a way to Configure HumanIK to use Z axis as Up?

Or is there another way around this? I see plenty articles on studios using HumanIK for Unreal so I must be missing something really silly in regards to this issue!

Any help will or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have resorted to using the ART Toolkit that ships with unreal since I am unable to find a resolution to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured our that on export you can switch the axis on export to work with the target engine allowing you to use HumanIK for unreal :D/